# two words as one value in user prompt read-host powershell

Tags: powershell, prompt, read-host

User Input has two words in it. for e.g. "Reflect UI" When the user presses the space key it treats "UI" as a 2nd word. You can see this also in the color change of the 2nd word. (changes to purple)  Is there a way to write the read-host prompt to allow a user to input two words that are supposed to be treated as one word?  Hopefully this makes sense. Believe it or not I have searched everywhere and for some reason no one has a solution.

[image]

Comment: Ignore the syntax highlighting in ISE - `Read-Host` will still return 1(!) string, not two

Comment: Prove: `(Read-Host).Count`

Comment: [The PowerShell ISE is no longer in active feature development](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support). [Windows terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/) has a more sophisticated syntax highlighting.

Comment: This whole time it was ISE confusing me.   thanks!